# error code 2, security Error: typescript blob

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, blob

I am trying to convert an image file to blob but get the error  below:

> {"code":2, "message":"SECURITY_ERR"}

Any idea why this might be happening?  I tried a lot of online resources but really could not find out what is going on.
I have the following code:

```
choose(){
this.filechooser.open().then((uri)=>{

  this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(uri).then((newurl)=>{

    let dirPath = newurl.nativeURL;

    alert(dirPath);

    let dirPathsegments = dirPath.split('/')
    dirPathsegments.pop();
    dirPath = dirPathsegments.join('/');

      this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(dirPath, newurl.name).then((buffer)=>{

      let blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: "image/jpeg"});

      alert('blob creation success');

    }, Error=>{
      alert('Blob Error '+ JSON.stringify(Error));
    });

  });
},Error=>{
  alert('Error Choosing File ' + Error);
});
}
```

Is there any other way to convert the file into a blob?
The current APIs that I am using only accepts Binary or Multipart attachments

Answer (score 1):

> It works. Tested on ionic 2 & 3

```
uploadFile() {
        this.fileChooser.open().then((url) => {

          (<any>window).FilePath.resolveNativePath(url, (nativeFilepath) => {

            this.readFileFromStorage(nativeFilepath);

          }
          )
        })
      }

      readFileFromStorage(nativeFilepath) {

        let fileName = this.getfilename(nativeFilepath);

        let fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

        let blogType = { type: 'image/'+fileExt };

        (<any>window).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(nativeFilepath, (res) => {
          res.file((resFile) => {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(resFile);
            reader.onloadend = (evt: any) => {

              var imgBlob = new Blob([evt.target.result], blogType);

              //Upload blob to firebase
              this.uploadToFirebase(imgBlob,fileName);
            }
          })
        })
      }

      getfilename(filePath){
        let fileName : string;
        fileName = filePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
        return fileName;
     }

    uploadToFirebase(fileBlob, name) {

        let storage = firebase.storage();

        storage.ref('images/' + name).put(fileBlob).then((d) => {
          alert("Done");
        }).catch((error) => {
          alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });

      }
```